# Need Horizontal Bar Char without any categories

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Hi
HighCharts
I need to acheive the above chart using highcharts.

1. Here - no categories to be shown
2. I need 3 data in a single series with custom color
3. The custom colors we need to change as per theme.

Please, let me know is it possible to achieve.

I tried to edit the sample but the chart is going way heighter than expected like. As codepen will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You should try to include your attempt (the one from the screenshot) as code. That way people can start from where you left of, instead of having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Such a chart can be achieved using a stacked bar chart, but you need to modify a lot of default elements to make it look like this. Take a look at the demo below and check the API documentation for what specific properties are responsible for.

The most complicated thing here was setting the X axis to show ticks nicely:

```js
yAxis: {
  reversed: true,
  opposite: true,
  min: 0,
  tickPositions: [0, 16, 16 + 42, 16 + 42 + 78],
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  tickWidth: 1,
  tickLength: 60,
  tickPosition: "inside",
  labels: {
    x: 10,
      y: 25,
    formatter: function() {
      let value = this.value - prevValue;
      prevValue = prevValue + value;

      return value < 0 ? '' : value;
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  }
},
```

The chart still requires refinement and automatic calculation of some tables, such as the one for the `yAxis.tickPositions` property.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tw5gcs31/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar